# What is the camera used by the scientists at the beginning of Titanic?

Tags: camcorder

In the film [Titanic](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120338/) [1997], the scientists (and mostly Bill Paxton's character) use a white camera as seen in these screenshots:

[image]

It looks like one of the Canon camcorders but it's not obvious what the brand and model are.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For what it's worth, that's a [Canon L1 Hi-8 camcorder](https://global.canon/en/c-museum/product/8mmvc336.html). The L2 was very similar in overall shape, but had a significantly different button layout.